# How to use table control in rdlc file without using any database in C# windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset, rdlc, reportviewer

I am working on project which is created in C# windows form application.And .net framework version 4.0

My project main form contains sub form PRINT which has reportviewer control. For that I created report.rdlc file. In my report I need 10 tables with 7 columns and 3 rows. but I don't want to use any database.

I think, I have to create dataset. 
If it is then how to create it without using database?

Comment: you can create it like this: `var dataset = new DataSet();`

Comment: You can create a DataSet or create a Class containing the properties which you need.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @Reza Aghaei. you can create a mock data with your table details and pass it into your controller. use the code below as reference.

```cs
public DataTable FinancialReportSub()
{
    DataTable table1 = new DataTable("Bk13");

    table1.Columns.Add("MainID");
    table1.Columns.Add("ID");
    table1.Columns.Add("Caption");
    table1.Columns.Add("Amount");
    table1.Columns.Add("MainCaption");
    var result = FinCustomData();

    foreach (DataRow item in result.Rows)
    {
        table1.Rows.Add(item["mainID"], item["id"], item["caption"], item["amount"], item["mainCaption"]);

    }

    return table1;
}

private DataTable FinCustomData()
{
    DataTable table1 = new DataTable("td");

    table1.Columns.Add("MainID");
    table1.Columns.Add("ID");
    table1.Columns.Add("Caption");
    table1.Columns.Add("Amount");
    table1.Columns.Add("MainCaption");
    // 0 - Normal, 1 - Header, 2 - Footer, 3 - Space

    table1.Rows.Add( "0", "1", "test1", "2000", "#CCCC00");

    table1.Rows.Add("1", "1", "0", "false", "#FFFFFF");
    table1.Rows.Add("2", "2", "20000", "false", "#FFFFFF");
    table1.Rows.Add("2", "1", "20000", "false", "#FFFFFF");
    table1.Rows.Add("1", "1", "40000", "true", "#FFFFFF");
    table1.Rows.Add("1", "0", "false", "3", "#FFFFFF");

    table1.Rows.Add("1", "2", "30000", "false", "#FFFFFF");
    table1.Rows.Add("1", "3", "30000", "false", "#FFFFFF");

    table1.Rows.Add("0", "1", "100000", "true", "#FFFFFF");
    table1.Rows.Add("30", "8", "false", "3", "#FFFFFF");

    table1.Rows.Add( "0", "2", "0", "false", "#FFFFFF");
    table1.Rows.Add( "1", "1", "30000", "false", "#FFFFFF");
    table1.Rows.Add( "1", "2", "30000", "false",  "#FFFFFF");
    table1.Rows.Add( "1", "2", "0", "false", "#FFFFFF");
    table1.Rows.Add("2", "1", "15000", "false",  "#FFFFFF");
    table1.Rows.Add("2", "2", "10000", "false", "#FFFFFF");
    table1.Rows.Add("2", "3", "5000", "false", "#FFFFFF");
    table1.Rows.Add("1", "2", "40000", "true", "#FFFFFF");
    table1.Rows.Add("2", "0", "false", "3", "#FFFFFF");
    table1.Rows.Add("0", "2", "100000", "true", "#FFFFFF");
    table1.Rows.Add( "0", "2", "0", "false", "#FFFFFF");

    return table1;
}
```